# I want to highlight all entries from a person (class), what am I missing here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a generator that generates random entries from people. **My goal is to mouseover an entry and have that highlight all of the other entries from that user.** Each entry gets assigned two classes, one which is the name of the user.

Here's the code I have below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){        

  var $body = $('div.center');
  $body.html('<header><p id="headertext">Twittler</p></header>');

  var index = streams.home.length - 1;
  while(index >= 0){
    var tweet = streams.home[index];
    var $tweet = $('<div class = "tweets"></div>');
    $($tweet).addClass(tweet.user);

    //I'm trying to have two classes here, and the ID. Probably don't need the ID.
    $($tweet).attr("id",tweet.user);  
    $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + Date().toString("hh:mm tt"));
    $tweet.appendTo($body);
    index -= 1;
  }

  $("#tweetButton").click('click', function(){
    index = 10;
      while(index >= 0){
      var tweet = streams.home[index];
      var $tweet = $('<div class = "tweets"></div>');
      $($tweet).addClass(tweet.user);

      //I'm trying to have two classes here, and the ID. Probably don't need the ID.
      $($tweet).attr("id",tweet.user);  
      $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + Date().toString("hh:mm tt"));
      $tweet.appendTo($body);
      index -= 1;
    }

  $('.tweets').on('mouseover',function(){
      var idget = $(this).attr('class');

      $('div.center').find(idget).css('background-color','pink');
    });


  });

});  //Ends Script area
```

The tweets on mouseover entry at the bottom is my attempt at doing this, but when I mouseover an entry nothing happens. I'd definitely appreciate your help on what I'm missing here to make this happen.

Comment: Where is your markup?

Answer (score 0):

so if I'm reading your code right (the onmouseover bit).. you grab the value of the `class` attribute and place it in the `idget` variable.  In this case that value will be `"tweets"`.  Next you request all `"tweets"` (as a selector) that are children of any `div` element with a `center` css `class` attribute, and set its background color.

If all that is correct, `"tweets"` is not a valid selector, unless you have markup that looks like:  `<tweets></tweets>`.  I believe you want:

```
$('div.center').find('.' + idget).css('background-color','pink');
```

Comment: In reply, when I grab the class attribute then idget will be the name of the class that you are mousing over (which will also be the name of the user).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your html page but my best guest is this:

first of all you can't use `id` for `tweet.user` because there can't be more than one element with same `id` so I suggest this code for `#tweetButton`:

```
  $("#tweetButton").click('click', function(){
  index = 10;
  while(index >= 0){
  var tweet = streams.home[index];
  var $tweet = $('<div class = "tweets"></div>');
  //$($tweet).addClass(tweet.user);

  //I'm trying to have two classes here, and the ID. Probably don't need the ID.
  $($tweet).attr("userid",tweet.user);  
  $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + Date().toString("hh:mm tt"));
  $tweet.appendTo($body);
  index -= 1;
}
```

for `mouseover` you should do this :

```
$('div.center').on('mouseover','.tweets',function(){
  var idget = $(this).attr('userid');

  $('div.center').find('[userid="'+idget+'"]').css('background-color','pink');
});
```

Comment: Hm this one didn't seem to work for me. I see what you are saying about the ID thing though.

Comment: is there any errors or not? although I told you I don't know much about the html side so the code is base on my guess.

Comment: make sure you change both part I changed and check for the `userid` if it set or not. Then for debugging run this `console.log(idget)` to see if it select your element or not?

Comment: I'll check it out tomorrow morning since it's pretty late here. I do appreciate your assistance in the matter.